# диалоговое окно с проверкой корректности ввода данных

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток

Я все так и не успел освоить js и $, но без их помощи видимо никак, а следовательно и без Вашей тоже) 
нужно простое окно, в которое будет введено имя, которое в дальнейшем будет передаваться на сервер. если в поле какие-то символы введены, то переходим на страничку, если нажата "Отмена" или поле осталось пустым, то должно вновь выскакивать первое окно

Думал реализовать как-то так, но в элзе, чтобы переводило на первый вопрос, или как минимум не переводило на страничку, а блокировало, но с функцией, что-то не работает, наверное что-то не так с кодом было(

```
 var person = prompt("введите свое имя");
 if (person) {
     }   else alert("Вы ввели не корректное имя, перезагрузите страницу, чтобы ваши данные сохранились");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = prompt('введи строку', '');
while(str != 'строка') {
str = prompt('введи строку', ''); 
}
location.replace('http://yandex.ru');
```

Answer (score 0):

pepel_xD, спасибо за помощь, но по предложенному коду, чтобы перейти на страницу нужно в поле ввода ввести именно "строка", мне же нужно, чтобы переходило по любому значению, кроме пустой строки

изменил условие, но теперь при нажатии в окне на "Отмена" тоже цикл прерывается, то есть можно попасть на страничку не вводя имя, или указав его, но нажав на кнопку "Отмена" передается null

этот вопрос так же, все еще вызывает интерес?) (1)

```
var str = prompt('введи строку', '');
while (str == '') {
   str = prompt('введи строку', ''); 
}
```

но полученная информация из первого ответа на пост привела к тому, что я решил изменить задачу и давать доступ, только людям с определенными именами и думал, что реализую это следующим образом:

```
var str = prompt('введи строку', '');
while (str != 'Вася' || str != 'Петя') {
    str = prompt('введи строку', ''); 
}
```

то есть, если ввели указанные имена, то все ок, проходим дальше, если же нет, то опять запрос на ввод имени, но почему то не работает, можно ли таким образом вводить условие в цикле? (2)

в конечном итоге реализовал так:

```
var str = prompt('введи строку', '');
while(str !='какой-то_ключ') {
    if (str == 'Вася') break;
    else if (str == 'Петя') break;
    str = prompt('введи строку', ''); 
}
```

на вопросы (1) и (2) все так же интересно получить ответы, так что с большой благодарностью приму помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо проверять введённое значение на:

1. Пустота строки (проверка на булево значение false);
2. ESC, отмена (проверка на null).

отсюда следует:

```
let userName = prompt("Enter ur name, pls");

while (userName == null || !userName ) {
  userName = prompt("Sorry.. repeat ur name, pls");
}
```

**В случае с отменой (esc) в prompt - значение переменной присваивается "null"**